# Using two separate DNS servers on the same domain

Tags: domains, dns

Why can't you use two separate DNS servers on a domain and update the `A Record` with where they should go?

```
ns1.domain1.com
ns2.domain1.com
ns1.domain2.com
ns2.domain2.com
```

The goal is to allow the sub-domains to use the `domain2.com` DNS and the `/public_html/` or `mydoaim.com` to use the DNS servers from `domain1.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hosts/registrars allow you to create NS records. You could then create a record like this:

```
subdomain.domain.tld  NS  ns3.domain.tld
```

This will delegate the request for the lookup to another nameserver. Naturally, passing that request will require contacting the nameservers of the primary domain, which is probably not something you want.

To be honest I couldn't think of a reason why you would want this; you might want to consider registering another domain.