# When are multiple nameservers used?

Tags: dns, nameserver

Inspired by this question: [Using two separate DNS servers on the same domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84027/using-two-separate-dns-servers-on-the-same-domain)

When you have multiple nameservers that resolve your domain, when is e.g. the ns2 used? Only when ns1 is offline?

Comment: It is a live spare (backup) in case one or the other fails. Often NS servers are taken in list order depending upon how a system is configured, however, some systems will pseudo load-balance by using all NS servers in a list.

Comment: @closetnoc I already thought they would be contacted by order on 'regular' systems. If you could put that in answer I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked as a network engineer during the earliest days of the Internet until I retired from that work. As well, I was a web host at one point and understand the original intent of having more than one DNS for hosting domain names. I am working off of older rules in this answer. Some of them may have been relaxed.

In the very early days, it was not uncommon for downtime and connectivity problems to effect resolving domain names. As a result, any DNS that is a SOA (statement of authority) was required to be hosted on two live systems. However, the problems did not stop there. It was further required that both name servers operating as a SOA reside on separate physical networks and that any domain name SOA not reside on a DNS that is a sub-domain of the domain itself.

In otherwords, example.com cannot have it's SOA on ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com. It was required that the example.com SOA to exist somewhere else such as ns1.examplednshost.com and ns2.examplednshost.com. Ns1.examplednshost.com and ns2.examplednshost.com would have to be on separate physical networks to remove any single point of failure. After that, ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com can be anything.

In my case when hosting sites, my domain name SOA was externally hosted by two other companies on two separate networks, however, the master DNS was on my domain. This means that the SOA DNS servers pulled from my master to populate their records. As well, my DNS servers were also an SOA for my domain (for simplicity- and not to be confused as my SOA as being official for my domain) and for many others that I hosted. Each DNS server resided on their own frame network. There were actually 5 DNS servers hosting my domain name and 4 of them pulled from the master in a cascading topology.

Having two NS servers is for fail-over. Often NS servers are taken in list order depending upon how a system is configured, however, some systems will pseudo load-balance by using all NS servers in a list.

Comment: The last paragraph is slightly wrong. If we are talking about authoritative nameservers they are a set (not a list). Typically nameservers will reply with them ordered (because bytes are ordered on the network) differently at each reply. The client is free to use any of them. Many recursive clients will try both, record the time they take to reply and try to stick with the fastest one, with the random probes of the other ones from time to time in case it would be good to switch to one of them instead. So it is by default load-balancing, all of them are used.

Comment: If we speak about recursive nameservers, like in `/etc/resolv.cong` then it is a list, the system only and always uses the first one... except if it does not reply at all for a given query and then it tries the second one, and so on. This is per request, so next request starts again with the first one.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Your are talking about a resolver and not a name server. These are two entirely different systems. Name servers are client/server models that are primarily designed to be public and queried externally where a resolver is designed to resolve names on the machine it resides on and expected to be private. The function of each is different and the behaviors are intentionally different. While both are simple, resolvers are especially simple by design to make resolution more user accessable. Resolvers also have build in limitations by design. Cheers!!

Comment: A resolver is a nameserver, a nameserver is a resolver. The dichotomy you create does not exist in real life. Resolvers (as in recursive nameserver to be precise) can be public, see `8.8.8.8`, `1.1.1.1` or `9.9.9.9`.  A nameserver role (authoritative or recursive) is mostly orthogonal to which clients can query it. The only existing separation is between the authoritative and the recursive roles. It can be the same code base: `bind` can act as both! recursive is not necessarily simpler than authoritative. The question was not clear on this point and your answer partially wrong.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree there is overlap, of course, because in part, a resolver does some of the same function as a name server, however the two are clearly not equivalent. Yes Bind can be queried by the same machine it resides on, however the methods of query between a resolver and DNS is decidedly different. One is internal to the OS function, the other is not. I am a retired system internals engineer and core networks engineer who wrote OSs, protocol stacks, device drivers, etc. including IP. While it has been a while since I had to get into the details, I do get the concept.

Comment: Again: your false separation between resolver and nameserver makes no sense and does not correspond to reality. But I will stop arguing, as you are even misreading me ("Bind can be queried by the same machine it resides on" this is absolutely not the point at all, nor anything I have said). "however the methods of query between a resolver and DNS is decidedly different" this is **completely WRONG**. There is only one DNS protocol, same one to query a recursive or authoritative nameserver. The OS API for applications is something completely different, you are strangely mixing everything...

Comment: I would also recommend to please stop repeating everywhere about your past life, this does not add any authority to your statements. Wrong remains wrong, whoever says it. And I do not need to give you the list of my current abilities in regards to the DNS and other topics to sustain my arguments, they stand by themselves.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Again, there is overlap, but designed for two different purposes. One localized, one not. My answer is about back when requirements for a name server to operate on the internet was different. It is indeed factual. NS on the internet cannot be the resolver. As far as my experience is concerned, I am not reading from a book. I lived this stuff for 30 years. I also state that I am retired and work from a different perspective. Queries to the resolver never exit the stack.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I want to be fair. It seems you and I are hung up on the fact that Bind is **a** resolver whereas resolv.conf is referred to as **the** resolver. They are both resolvers. I see one as a car for personal use and the other as a truck for commercial use. I am sure we are just misunderstanding each other. Let's save it for another day. Cheers!!

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is a file, not a software. I can not compare that to a software, like `bind` (besides the obvious fact that this file is for Unix system, what would you use as comparison on Windows or MacOS systems?). Anyway, I think our debate is moot, so I will let it rest here.

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is Google **Public** DNS **resolver** (see https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/ : Public DNS is only a name resolver.) Same for CloudFlare and `1.1.1.1` and Quad9 with `9.9.9.9`. They are public, anyone can query them with queries exiting their stack, and they are resolvers, as they "just" resolve names on your behalf. They are nameservers in fact (because they speak the DNS protocol over the wire), running `bind` or equivalent, in recursive mode. And all of these would have been the same 30 years ago if these companies existed then, nothing has changed in the protocol.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes it is a file. It is the config file for *the resolver*. There is a Windows equivalent, but I am not a Windows guy. Nor a Mac guy. So I cannot comment on those. Cheers!!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek *...is Google Public DNS resolver...* Yes! These are name servers. They are resolvers. But not what is referred to *the resolver* using the resolv.conf file. Similar, but different. I lived in the DNS world deeply when working. I performed audits for NetSol yearly before their certifications to ensure compliance. I wrote code for ARPA-NET back in the day. I got this.

Comment: So now resolvers are nameservers? You just said they are different in a comment above (*however the two are clearly not equivalent.* I cite). It is impossible to follow things that way, if you change arguments at each step. I am happy that each comment lets you give us mere mortals more insight of your past vast experience (obviously my plea to stop pulling the authority argument was not granted), but that does not replace wrong information or misconceptions, specially if you are not open to reevaluate things. That will be all for me. Cheers as you say.

Comment: FWIW Network Solutions started doing .COM management in 1991 or 1993.... hardly 30 years ago but we are probably not missing another imprecision. Cheers.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes! A name server is a resolver. A resolver is a generic term and applies in more than one area. I did not say I worked for NetSol 30 years ago, but I did work on IP router software in the early to mid 80s before/during the transition from DARPA to public. These were PDPs back in my DEC days.